# Django - WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Get'

Tags: django, django-views

So I have 2 scenerios in which one works and one doesnt. I set up a select box in the html template with some hard coded options which you can see in Scenrio2.
Im curious to know why Scenario2 works with no problems and Scenario1 throws this error. I have also attached the stack trace below.

---

Scenario1(Doesnt Work):

```
    current_status = 'All'
    status_list = []

    all_status = RequisitionStatus.objects.all()
    for status in all_status:
        status_list.append(status.status)

    if request.Get.get('Filter') in status_list:
        user_req_lines_incomplete = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(Q(parent_req__username=request.user) & Q(status__status=request.Get.get('Filter')))
        current_status = request.Get.get('Filter')
    else:
        user_req_lines_incomplete = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(parent_req__username=request.user).exclude(status__status='Completed')
```

Scenario 2(works):

```
if request.GET.get('Filter') == 'Created':
        user_req_lines_incomplete = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(Q(parent_req__username=request.user) & Q(status__status='Created'))
        current_status = 'Created'
    elif request.GET.get('Filter') == 'For Assistance':
        user_req_lines_incomplete = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(Q(parent_req__username=request.user) & Q(status__status='For Assistance'))
        current_status = 'For Assistance'
    elif request.GET.get('Filter') == 'Assistance Complete':
        user_req_lines_incomplete = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(Q(parent_req__username=request.user) & Q(status__status='Assistance Complete'))
        current_status = 'Assistance Complete'
    elif request.GET.get('Filter') == 'Assistance Rejected':
        user_req_lines_incomplete = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(Q(parent_req__username=request.user) & Q(status__status='Assistance Rejected'))
        current_status = 'Assistance Rejected'
    else:
        user_req_lines_incomplete = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(parent_req__username=request.user).exclude(status__status='Completed')
```

### StackTrace:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Kevin.Pardo\Documents\Python\venv\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Kevin.Pardo\Documents\Python\venv\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Kevin.Pardo\Documents\Python\venv\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kevin.Pardo\Documents\Python\venv\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kevin.Pardo\Documents\Python\django\lambda\req\views.py" in pending_action
  241.     if request.Get.get('Filter') in status_list:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /req/pending/
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Get'
```

Comment: You wrote `request.Get` in your view instead of `request.GET`.

Comment: Wow that is so embarrassing. I knew it should have worked equivalently because i tested it in the shell. Thank you for catching that for me

Answer (score 5):

It has nothing to do with the approach you followed. In your first approach you write:

```
if request.Get.get('Filter') in status_list:
  # ...
```

Like the error says, the `request` object has no `Get` attribute, only a `GET` attribute. You make the same mistake over the rest of the view.

So you can fix this with:

```
if request.GET.get('Filter') in status_list:
  # ...
```

You furthermore also wrote `parent_req__username=request.user` in the filtering (of both views), I think it might be better to use `parent_req=request.user`, or `parent_req__username=request.user.username`).

You can in fact improve this a bit further like:

```
current_status = 'All'
all_status = RequisitionStatus.objects.values_list('status', flat=True)
filter = request.GET.get('filter')

if filter in status_list:
    user_req_lines_incomplete = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(
        parent_req=request.user,
        status__status=filter
    )
    current_status = filter
else:
    user_req_lines_incomplete = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(
        parent_req=request.user
    ).exclude(
        status__status='Completed'
    )
```

Comment: Yes thank you, my scenrio2 was meant for testing purposes then i decided to condense the code and made silly errors. I kept over looking "Get" having to be GET

Comment: @K.Pardo: well I would advise to read the error message. Python actually has - compared to other environments - pretty good exception messages to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Sometimes another pair of eyes is necessary to see a problem. I knew what the problem was but kept looking over Get. Its easy to mix the 2 up. I understand what you're saying though. Thank you for the advise.